# SVN: remote access isn't working

Tags: apache, svn, remote-access

I've installed subversion and apache on my pc. I can access to my repository using followinf url

```
http://localhost/svn/repos/
```

Now I want other members of my group to access the project files I've put in my repository. As it's my first time using svn I looked for the solutions and I think I'm a bit lost.

I read about port forwarding in my router so I opened my router interface. I went to NAT/PAT section of my router configuration and added a new rule with following caracteristics:

```
Application: svn
External port:3690
Internal port:80
protocol : TCP
equipment: myPC
```

And Checked the option "Active". But I think I'm missing something. 
I read in an article that to verify if the remote access is working i have to go to

```
svn://83.200.108.71
```

While it doesn't work. "unable to connect.."
Can someone please help me .

Comment: Does: svn://83.200.108.71:3690 work?

Comment: Why are you accessing it comming via router with svn whereas in the others accessing it via http ? Have you setup the svnserve daemon ? Or did you use Apache module?

Comment: @khmarbaise i used an apache module. Does it matter? Do I have to change it? And yes I've followed instructions in the link http://willperone.net/Code/svnserver.php

Comment: If you are using the apache module than you can't access via svn protocol and it does not make sense to open your firewall for svn protocoll (port: 3690 etc.). You need to open it for port 80 (http) protocol...

Comment: @khmarbaise can you please explain more I'm totally new to this and it's getting really confusing :s

Comment: You need to change the external port to 80 as well. BUT BE VERY CAREFULL ON OPENING YOUR FIREWALL!!!!! Why not using services like sourceforge or other services ...? What kind of group this is?

Comment: @khmarbaise i'm a student in software programming and i have many projects in groups that's why I want to use svn .

Comment: No support of the high school / university ? What about git using github or similar tools....Have you changed the port but i repeat...VERY CAREFUL ABOUT OPENING THE FIREWALL ! I wouldn't do that!

Answer (score 1):

Wait... You can access your repository via `http://`? Why not let others access the repository using `http://`?

Don't do anything with your router. Don't muck with ports. Apache httpd is serving your repository just fine off of Port 80. Tell your users to simply access your repository via `http://<machineName>/svn/repos`. That's all there is to it.

`svn://` is a completely different protocol than `http://`. Port 3690 just happens to be the default port of `svn://`, but that doesn't mean if you reroute your `http://` protocol there, everything will work.

Most of the time, people who first use Subversion set up the `svnserve` server instead of Apache httpd because it's easier than using Apache http. Here's how you setup a repository to use `svn://`:

```
$ svnadmin create my_repos        #
$ vi my_repos/conf/svnserve.conf  #Need to denop 'password-db=passwd' line
$ vi my_repos/conf/passwd         #Need to setup user accounts
$ svnserve -r my_repos -d
```

And that's it. Now your users can access the repository via `svn://<machineName>`.

Although svnserve is simpler and easier than Apache (and faster), there are many reasons to use Apache httpd over svnserve:

- Port 80 is likely not blocked by network while port 3690 maybe blocked
- You can let Apache httpd use LDAP for authentication (which can also allow Windows Active Directory authentication)
- Apache httpd can service multiple repositories while `svnserve` can only service a single repository on port 3690.